# Can't add/change items through CollectionEditor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a collection, to which I want to add/change items through VS collection editor. Collection goes like this:

```
[Browsable(true)]
[Category("Other")]
[Description("Gets or sets items of the menu")]
[NewItemTypes(typeof(MenuItem))]
public List<MenuItem> Items
{
     get
     {
          return items;
     }
     set
     {
          items = value;
     }
}

private List<MenuItem> items;
```

MenuItem is my own wpf user control class with some string property, which is the content of Label indeed:

```
public string Description
{
   get
   {
      return MenuLabel.Content.ToString();  
   }
   set
   {
      MenuLabel.Content = value;    
   }
}
```

Add button in collection editor is working but when I'm trying to save, I'm getting exception of "object reference not set..." with error "Unexpected error occurred in value dialog editor". When editing the Description field I'm getting error "Property value is not valid" with same exception. Do you know how to make it working?